# Can I fly to Germany with a Travel Decument Form i-327 without visa?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

I have an I-327 US Travel Document , a permanent Residence and Re-Entry Permit. I know I can re-enter into the US. But can I fly to Germany? Do I need a tourist visa? My trip is only a month. Thank you!

Comment: Virtually nowhere accepts the I-327 travel document for visa-free travel. If you are a refugee or asylum status, you should instead obtain the I-571 Refugee Travel Document, which is actually accepted in some countries (including Germany) for visa-free travel. If you have a passport of another country, and are not a refugee from that country, you might also use it.

Answer (score 1):

The European Union keeps a spreadsheet of [recognised travel documents](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-recognised-documents.html) which entitles the holder to cross the external borders and which may be endorsed with a visa. Here's the relevant section:

[image: USA documents recognized by the EU]

As you can see, you can -- and as we will see, you actually need to -- use this document to apply for a visa to Germany.

To answer whether you need a visa, check the German Missions in the United States [Visa: Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/faq-visa/899734) page:

> Holders of the “Refugee Travel Document” (Form I-571) which is issued by the United States Department of Homeland Security (DHS) are not required to obtain a visa to enter the Federal Republic of Germany for purposes of business, tourism, or to visit friends if they stay no longer than 90 days. The Travel Document must be valid for at least four months after entering Germany.
>
> Please be advised that this regulation applies to Germany only. If you plan to transit or travel to other Schengen countries you have to contact the responsible consular mission of the respective countries to find out about their visa regulations. **Please also note that holders of the very similar document called “Permit to Re-Enter” (Form I-327) do not fall under this rule. Holders of a “Permit to Re-Enter” must apply for a visa.**
>
> If you are in doubt whether you are a holder of a “Permit to Re-Enter” or a “Refugee Travel Document” please refer to the data page of the document in your possession issued by DHS. More information on the type of document issued to you can be found above and below the photo in your document.

Emphasis mine. Two more notes:

1. The I-571 document mentioned here gives you significantly more freedom of movement -- you wouldn't need a visa with that one. If you are eligible for it, you should get it.
2. Malta and Denmark won't recognize your document *at all* and Spain only recognises it for transit or exit to return to the United States. This could be relevant for example if you would attempt to fly Norwegian Airlines via Copenhagen -- that won't work. But, again, if you had an I-571, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your answer wasn‘t clear, I need a visa to enter Germany, or I need a visa if I attempt to fly via Copenhagen ? I will travel via Morroco

Comment: @AhmadAlAjmi You need a visa to enter any Schengen member state with the I-327 travel document, except Denmark and Malta which do not recognize the document at all and will not issue a visa in it.

Comment: @AhmadAlAjmi another reorganization of the answer. Is it clear now?